# Exchange MoveRequest stalled: TotalStalledDueToCIDuration

Tags: exchange-2013

I have queued a bunch of `New-MoveRequest` to do an intra-org move of a bunch of mailboxes between databases. However the mailboxes are small, but have been stalled for over an hour.

`Get-MoveRequestStatistics` shows:

```
TotalStalledDueToCIDuration            : 00:59:03
```

What is CI, why is it stalling and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pause due to Content Indexing. [KB 2807668](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2807668) tells us that the AD Prep does not actually do everything it's meant to. To finish the job:

> 1. Create a new Active Directory group that is named "ContentSubmitters" and then grant Admistrators and NetworkService
>      full access to the group. This is a dummy group and should be used as
>      a placeholder only. You might want to add a description so that the
>      group is not removed.
> 2. Force or wait for Active Directory replication.
> 3. Restart the following services:
>
>    - Microsoft Exchange Search
>    - Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller

Creating this group anywhere in your AD and adding those permissions has put my mailbox indexing back to "Healthy" and the move requests completed within a few minutes of restarting the services.

It's important to note that you don't need to add any users into that group, and by "Full Access" Microsoft means the security of the group:

[image]